# A div is added with id=shadowLL in chrome when I open my html file with live server

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, liveserver

I've written some HTML and CSS code and everytime when I run it through live server there is a div added with an id=shadowLL and in that div there is another div that says #shadow-root (open).

When I open the exact same file from my explorer this div is not added, but when I use live server it's added. And when I use live server in combination with firefox it's not added. So it's only adding that div when I use live server in combination with chrome.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the problem, without changing from browser and without having to write extra css just to hide this div?

I've tried another browser and not using liveserver and that works fine, also writing some css to hide the div works.

Comment: First suspect would probably be some browser extension ... Does the problem persist, if you test in a _private_ Chrome window, with all extensions disabled?

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem, I'll search wich extension that causes this problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this issue, it seems to be caused by the [Lean Library](https://leanlibrary.com/) browser extension. Disabling the extension got rid of the `shadowLL` div for me.